# Create multiple dynamic dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple text files. Each file is a list of animals and their counts for a house. Like this:

houseA.txt

```
cats 3  
dogs 1  
birds 4
```

houseB.txt

```
cats 5  
dogs 3  
birds 1
```

I have about 20 houses and each house has about 16000 species (so each file has about 16000 lines. All houses have the same species, just different counts for each specie.

My current script loops through each file, line by line, and captures the house, specie name and its count.

I want to create a dictionary of houses, where each house is a dictionary of animals and their counts. So from the example above, the result would look like this:

```
dictOfDicts{houseA:{'cats': 3, 'dogs': 1, 'birds': 4}, houseB:{'cats': 5, 'dogs': 3, 'birds': 1}}
```

In case you're wondering, this will later be turned into a table:

```
      house:   A   B
animal         
  cats         3   5
  dogs         1   3
 birds         4   1
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys


houseL = []
dictList = []
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as files:
    for f in files:
        f = f.rstrip()
        with open(f, 'r') as aniCounts:
            house = str(aniCounts).split(sep='/')[2]  # this and the next line captures the house name from the file name.
            house = house.split('.')[0]
            houseL.append(house)

            for line in aniCounts:
                ani = line.split()[0]
                count = line.split()[1]
                #print(ani, ' ', count)
```

EDIT: Changed question to dict of dicts, thanks to a helpful commenter.

Comment: Please post the code for your current script. Also, that result is not a valid Python list. Do you actually want a dict of dicts? I.e. `{'houseA': {...}, 'houseB': {...}}`

Comment: You are right! I do want a dictionary of dictionaries...

Comment: So do you have another file containing the list of text files? If not you don't need the first `open`.

Comment: @ Paul Rooney how would Python know that "house" is a file name then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
house_names = ['houseA', 'houseB', ...]
houses_dict = {}

for house in house_names:
    houses_dict[house] = {}

    with open(house + '.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            species, num = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)  # split off rightmost word
            houses_dict[house][species] = int(num)
```

The result will then be (e.g.):

```
houses_dict = {
    'houseA': {
        'cats': 3
        'dogs': 1
        'birds': 4
    },
    'houseB': {
        'cats': 5
        'dogs': 3
        'birds': 1
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very clean code. I like it. 
But I'm getting a KeyError for the very first entry 'cats' .

Comment: Hmmm. Just tested and it works for me. Did you get a KeyError while running the code, or while using `houses_dict` afterwards?

Comment: `line.rsplit(1)`  would be better there, as it would allow  species names to have spaces.

Comment: @Glubbdrubb on which line does the exception occur?

Comment: `houses_dict[house][species] = int(num)`

Comment: @Glubbdrubb did you make any changes to the code at all? e.g. to handle command line arguments? If so, please edit the new code into the question. Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: a DictReader automagically handels quoted string inputs - not quite as magic as `rsplit(1)` does, but maybe cleaner.

Comment: @Phydeaux, I figured it out! I don't have a list of houses, like you do. I create that list while looping through the list of file names. So I missed the line `houses_dict[house] = {}` which explains the error I got.
Also, sorry about the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

One more version:

```
from path import Path

dir_path = '/TEMP'

files_ls = [x for x in Path(dir_path).files() if 'house' in str(x)]

def read_file(path):
    lines = dict([row.strip().split(' ') for row in path.open(encoding='utf-8')])
    return lines

all_data = dict([(str(x.name),read_file(x)) for x in files_ls])

print(all_data)
```

Output:

```
{'house1.txt': {u'birds': u'4', u'cats': u'3', u'dogs': u'1'}}
```

Comment: does not work for the rare `Tibateean Pushelwushel Groundhog` - just in case it lives in any of the houses

Comment: sure there should be special care for names but there is no point in guessing (quotes, multiple spaces, special chars etc) as it was not specified in the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to split yourself, use a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and ensure any animal with spaces inside its name is quoted in the file:

```
from csv import DictReader

d = {}
files = ["h1.csv","h2.csv"]

for f in files:
  with open(f,"r",encoding="utf8",newline="") as  houseData:
    d[f] = {} # dict per house
    for row in DictReader(houseData, fieldnames=["animal","count"], delimiter=' ' ):
      d[f][row["animal"]] = int(row["count"])  # access by given fieldnames

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'h1.csv': {'cats': 3, 'dogs': 1, 'birds': 4}, 
 'h2.csv': {'cats': 5, 'dogs': 3, 'birds': 1, 'insects': 2402, 'Blue Flutterwings': 2}}
```

*File* h1.csv

```
cats 3
dogs 1
birds 4
```

*File* h2.csv

```
cats 5
dogs 3
birds 1
insects 2402
"Blue Flutterwings" 2
```

**Caveat:** If you harbour `Green Cantilopes` or `Blue Flutterwings` in your house, you have to quote them in the file - thats where this solution starts to shine - as it will automagically handle quoted strings in combination with `' '`  as delimiter .

Comment: dear downvoter, please leave constructive feedback so I can learn something.